Flutter: Why is open ai variations throwing a 400 error when posting a list of ints
I use the multipartRequest to post to openai an image variation request and  I am getting 400 error message. Everything looks good. how can I see why open ai is rejecting my payload
import 'package:mime/mime.dart';
import 'package:http_parser/http_parser.dart';
import 'dart:html' as html;


final Uri url = Uri.parse('https://api.openai.com/v1/images/variations');

      final request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', url)
        ..headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer $apiKey'
        ..files.add(http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(
          'image',
          Uint8List.fromList(_bytesFromPicker as List<int>),
          contentType: MediaType.parse('image/png'),
        ))
        ..fields['n'] = '1' // Number of variations to generate
        ..fields['size'] = '1024x1024'; // Size of the generated images

      // Send the request
      final response = await request.send();
      debugPrint("response sent");
      debugPrint(response.statusCode.toString());
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
       
      }

Error Message:
{
  "error": {
    "code": null,
    "message": "Missing image file in request. (Perhaps you specified `image` in the wrong format?)",
    "param": null,
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}

